# executeQuery ERROR for JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Hi I'm new to JDBC and ran into `executeQuery` error while constructing the JDBC. I just want to display all the information in the `student` table. I used the `prepareStatement` and I didn't set any parameter since I don't have. It works when use `createStatement`.

This is the error I'm getting

```
The method executeQuery(String) in the type Statement is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

How can I get it working using `prepareStatement`.

```
public class Test3 extends JFrame{

    Vector rowData,columnNames;
    JTable jt = null;
    JScrollPane jsp = null;

    Connection myConn = null;
    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;

    //constructor
    public Test3() {
        columnNames = new Vector();
        rowData = new Vector();

        columnNames.add("Student_ID");
        columnNames.add("Name");
        columnNames.add("Gender");
        columnNames.add("Age");
        columnNames.add("DOB");
        columnNames.add("Major");

        try {
            //1. Get a connection to database
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stu?useSSL=false","root","1972");

            //2. Create a prepareStatement
            myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("Select * from student");

            // 3. Set the parameters
            // no need to set the parameters, because there is not parameter needed to be set

            // 4. Execute SQL query
            ***myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();***

            while(myRs.next()) {
                Vector col = new Vector();
                col.add(myRs.getString(1));
                col.add(myRs.getString(2));
                col.add(myRs.getString(3));
                col.add(myRs.getInt(4));
                col.add(myRs.getString(5));
                col.add(myRs.getString(6));

                rowData.add(col);
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(myRs!=null) myRs.close();
                if(myStmt!=null) myStmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
    }

}
```

Comment: You dont say what your error is, I'm assuming it doesn't compile becsuse the method doesn't exist on Statement. Assign the prepared statement to a variable of type PreparedStatement.

Comment: Try using `PreparedStatement myStmt = null;` instead of `Statement myStmt = null;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong method. For **Statement**, the definition of **executeQuery** is 
 `ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException;`
For **PreparedStatement**, the difinition is `ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException;`

So you can either use `PreparedStatement myStmt = null;` or `myRs = ((PreparedStatement )myStmt).executeQuery();`